# How do I make it so that I don't need to source everytime I open up my terminal?

Tags: bash, terminal, shell-script, bashrc

Due to the way I downloaded a certain program [Gromacs], every time I open a terminal to use `gmx`, I must do the following and would like to make it so I don't need to do this every time:

```
cd ~/Downloads/GromacsDownload/gromacs-2021.2/build
source /usr/local/gromacs/bin/GMXRC
```

- I created a script [`gmxAssign.sh`] containing:

  ```bsh
  #!/bin/bash

  source /usr/local/gromacs/bin/GMXRC
  ```
- I added this command to `~/.bashrc`:

```
bash /home/myuser/Downloads/GromacsDownload/gromacs-2021.2/build/gmxAssign.sh
```

thinking this would work, but when I close the terminal and open a new one, I get the same result [`Command 'gmx' not found`]:

Is there another way to make this permanent?

Comment: Try adding the executables' path [`/usr/local/gromacs/bin/`] to the `PATH` variable within `.bashrc`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the code you have added to `.bashrc`. This should be something like `. /usr/local/gromacs/bin/GMXRC` or `. ~/path/to/gmxAssign.sh`.

Comment: @Bodo The path is in the 2nd bullet, but appears the OP removed the code fence for some reason

Comment: @Os-Gs Sentences shouldn't be broken by code boxes, as it discombobulates, which is why I made the grammatical correction _(you may not have realized it, but you also removed the code fences for the code box - monospaced code should always be specified as such to properly display when translated by web translators and to ensure it copies correctly across OSes)_

Comment: Sorry this is my first time using StackOverflow, thank you very much for the help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command
`bash /home/myuser/Downloads/GromacsDownload/gromacs-2021.2/build/gmxAssign.sh`
will run your script in a subshell, so it will not affect the current shell.

Instead you should use the following command to run your script in the current shell:

```bash
. /home/myuser/Downloads/GromacsDownload/gromacs-2021.2/build/gmxAssign.sh`
```

Since your script contains only one command you can alternatively use this command directly in `.bashrc`:

```bash
. /usr/local/gromacs/bin/GMXRC
```